# Avada Theme Customization

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I want to build WP Website using Avada theme, but I dont want to use builder.

I would like to custom code most of the content with adding some elements that theme provides.

Anyone with Avada experience that can advise if Avada is good for custom coding?

Answer (score 0):

Working with Avada for a while now, the builder itself gives You custom code options.
If You want to create a php template from scratch, Avada wont help here and You will have no functionality available.

It is purely for creating pages with the builder itself, You can do many hacks with JS\JQ and HTML but sometimes its a pain cause it has its own grid size and it wraps divs in a lot of other divs which I dont like.

Practicaly works like Elementor, nice to make LP's faster but lacks a lot of customization options in my opinion.

Comment: What do you think about Bricks theme? Looks quite good, and made more for developers then other themes!? What theme do you recommend for someone who doesnt use only drag and drop, but codes html/css/js!?

Comment: Well, I use code, and tbh most of the theme Im using is custom made, the Avada is only for quick LP's that I want to add but theme customization is done on my side without using Avada...

Answer (score 0):

Avada does have a code block option and you can create your own custom templates and upload them and call them.

Now I've never tried to embed any fancy code in this but I have created custom templates.

There's a default editor, a builder and a live builder - although I don't know how it would behave on a custom coded template.